# 2008 Honda CG 125 - Do I Need To Fully Screw in My Dipstick To Check the Oil?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, oil, dipstick

I went to check the oil level on my Honda CG 125 and noticed nothing came up. However, it was on uneven ground. I then moved my bike to a flatter level and screwed my dipstick all the way in, where I did see oil on it.

I have in the past only dipped it in and oil was there so there hasn't been any definitive answer to this.

Should I fully screw in the dipstick to check the oil level or can I get away with dipping it in?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @treyBake I don't know what procedure Honda specifies for this operation. To measure engine oil levels on dipstick-equipped BMW motorcycles from the 50s through the 80s, one put the dipstick in place but did not screw it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an English edition of the owners manual online [here](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Honda-Cg125-Fan-3643865.html):

This wording appears in the "Maintenance" section:

*5. Reinstall the oil filler cap/dipstick. Check for oilleaks.*

*6. Start the engine and let it idle for 3 – 5 minutes.*

*7. 2 – 3 minutes after stopping the engine, check that the oil level is at the upper level mark on the oil fillercap/dipstick with the motorcycle upright on firm,level ground. Make sure there are no oil leaks.*

Step 5 says that the dipstick must be "reinstalled," which suggests to me that it should be screwed in completely.

Comment: I agree, screwed in... plus 1 from me for finding it.